# Accessing base class typedef in derived class template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to access a typedef member in base class from derived class template. In template name of template parameter is same as name of typdef in base class.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class no {
    public :
    typedef int T;
};
template<typename T> class no1 : public no {
    public :
    T obj;
};
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    no1<string> o ; o.obj = "1";
    return 0;
}

14:24: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'no::T {aka int}' [-fpermissive]
  no1<string> o ; o.obj = "1";
```

In above code T is obj is always of type int. How can I force obj to be of template parameter and not typdef declared in base class ?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot without providing an explicit conversion from `T` to `int`. Also note, that the `T` template parameter just _shadows_ `no::T`, these are unrelated.

Comment: That's what my question is how to access T template parameter without changing base class or renaming template parameter ?

Comment: I'm afraid there really is no way. See http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#459

Comment: by the way, I wonder why this is being downvoted. It's clear, it's an MCVE and the answer is all but obvious.

Comment: There is one way to hack around this by making `no1` derive from a base that is dependent (interpose a class template in the interitance hierarchy between `no1` and `no`). Would that be an acceptable change for you? Note that the hack will work on GCC and Clang, but not on MSVC currently. cc @ChristianHackl

Answer (score 0):

this works for me :

```
template<typename T> class no1;
template<typename T>
struct underlying_type_of;

template<typename T>
struct underlying_type_of<no1<T> >
{
   typedef T type;
};
template<typename T> class no1 : public no {
public :
  typename underlying_type_of<no1>::type obj;
};
```